# Defining a function with global parameters

Tags: function-construction

What I would like to do in Mathematica is something like

```
f[x_] := a x
g[a_] := NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

But then of course  I get

```
g[1]
    NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand a x has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}. >>
Out= NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

But I found that I can circumvent the problem with

```
g[a_] := Hold[NIntegrate][f[x], {x, 0, 1}] // Evaluate // ReleaseHold // Evaluate
    NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand a x has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}. >>
g[1]
Out= 0.5
```

I don't really understand why this works nor why the definition of `g` throws an error. As I haven't found any other solution to my problem, I would really like to understand why my "solution" works which should also provide an answer to whether there is a simpler solution.

(I understand I can solve this simple problem with `f[x_, a_]` but I have in fact a more complex environment in hand where this approach becomes inconvenient.)

Comment: It becomes inconvenient because I have more oen parameters and later define other functions based on `f` which I then use in different combinations. So I would have to type expressions like `g[x,a,b,c]h[g[x,a,b,c],a,b,c]` instead of much clearer `g[x]h[g[x]]`. This wouldn't matter if I was creating static code, but I am in fact prototyping and trying different combinations all the time.

Comment: OK, but you still didn't explain why my suggestion wouldn't work, i.e. encapsulate those parameters into the function at the beginning.

Comment: Try defining `g` as `g[aa_] := Block[{a = aa}, NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]]`.

Comment: @Nasser Because later I might want to do something like `(f[x]^2 Sin[f[x]]+Cos[f[x]]/.a->1)+(f[x]^3 Cos[f[x]]+Sin[f[x]]/.a->2)`. Now I can of course do that easily with `f[x,a]`, but it will be much more typing and during prototyping and with more parameters, it quickly becomes very time-consuming.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov This works nicely, thanks! Now the original question remains unanswered, but I don't need the answer anymore and I'm not sure whether the question is worthy in general?

Comment: @azag0 I have added an answer so you can accept it. I also renamed the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is to define `g` as:

```
g[aa_] := Block[{a = aa}, NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

This works because `f[x]` now is evaluated in local environment where variable `a` has a value.

The reason why the version

```
g[a_] :=  NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

does not work is that `a` is absent on the right side of the definition, so nothing will be replaced: `SetDelayed` (`:=`) creates a `RuleDelayed` replacement rule which performs *lexical* scoping. So evaluating for example `g[1]` is equivalent to evaluation of `g[a]` or any other such construct.

---

Your "solution" is essentially equivalent to

```
g[a_] = NIntegrate[Evaluate@f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

In both cases the real replacement rule generated contains the variable `a` on the right hand side:

```
?g
```

> ```
> g[a_]=NIntegrate[a x,{x,0,1}]
> ```